# Brightness of screen to dark, no regulation possible

Tags: screen, brightness

I have installed on a Laptop Ubuntu 11.10 (Oneiric Ocelot), it's working fine, but the screen is mutch to dark and no regulation is possible. Grafic card: ATI Mobility Radeon X1350.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for **Screen** under **System Settings**.